# How can we sort entites of createEntityAdapter based on table columns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, columnsorting

I'm using [Redux-toolkit with entityAdapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) for state mangement in my React App. I want to apply table sorting for each column where my table rows are entities of Redux-toolkit entityAdapter. I want to change the sortComparer fuction like this in my reducer.

```
sortEntities: (state,action) =>{
return {
...state,
sortComparer:(a:myEntityType,b:myEntityType)=> a.title.localCompare(b.title)
};
},
```

I dispatch sortEntities action on onClick handler of columns. This sort of changing the sortComparer is not throwing any rules voilation error but not working. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you really intend to use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)? In other words, have you a typo in your code, or is it just a copy/paste typo into the question post?

Comment: No it's copy/paste... Sorry, my bad... let me check. Thanks for pointing out 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in the above code is storing a `function` to the `sortComparer` property of your state.  You aren't actually *applying* the sort function anywhere, and it's not advisable to store non-serializable data like functions in Redux.

The adapter that you create by calling `createEntityAdapter` is an object which helps you interact with the state.  The state itself is just an array of `ids` and a dictionary object of `entities`.  The `sortComparer` property of the adapter is not part of the state, so it cannot be modified by modifying the state.

---

There are a lot of ways to approach this.

For example, you could select all entities of Redux and sort them locally.

```
const useSortedEntities = (sortBy) => {
   // get an array of entities with the selector from the entity adapter
   const allEntities = useSelector(selectEntities);

   // sort based on the current property
   // use ... to avoid mutation
   // would probably want to memoize this
   return [...allEntities].sort(
     (a, b) => a[sortBy].localCompare(b[sortBy])
   );
}
```

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
   const [sortProperty, setSortProperty] = useState('author');

   const sortedList = useSortedEntities(sortProperty);
...
```

Or you could `dispatch` an action with the sort property in the payload and save the sort property in Redux.  You can then use `createSelector` to create a selector for the sorted data.

```
const mySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'someName',
    initialState: myAdapter.getInitialState({
       // additional properties to include in initial state
       sortBy: 'author'
    }),
    reducers: {
       sortEntities: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
           state.sortBy = action.payload;
       }
...
```

```
const selectSortedEntities = createSelector(
   // first select entities with the selector from the adapter
   selectEntities,
   // next select the sort order
   (state: RootState) => state.pathToSlice.sortBy
   // then combine them to return a sorted array
   (allEntities, sortBy) => [...allEntities].sort(
        (a, b) => a[sortBy].localCompare(b[sortBy])
   );
)
```

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
   const sortedList = useSelector(selectSortedEntities);
   
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
   const onClick = () => {
       dispatch(sortEntities('title'));
   }
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Linda! I have used the second approach with a little difference. I sorted entities in a thunkAction and passed sorted entities to corresponding extraReducer of createSlice.

Comment: @DevLoverUmar, your solution sounds much better than the ones above. While the ones in the accepted answer will do the work, the whole idea of having the items sorted in store gets lost. Depending on the use-case this could be good or bad. So thanks for your comment above. And the question.